# How to add axes for subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to fit a function to a large number of datasets stored in several files and compare the fits. I open a file, read the columns and plot each fit as a subplot after fitting. Eventually I have a figure with lot of subplots showing all the fits. However, I need to see the fit and also the residual for each subplot like in the figure.

So far, I have the following. I thought I could add axes to subplot but it does not work. The function that I have works. But I do not know how to add axes to subplot to plot the residual with the fit as a subplot to the subplot.

```
def plotall(args):    
x=args[0]
ydata=args[1]
chisq=args[2]
fit=args[3]
g1=args[4]
a=args[5]
ptitle=args[6]

axi = fig1.add_subplot(a1,b1,a+1)
axi.plot(x, ydata,'ko',markersize=2,label='Data')
axi.plot(x,fit,'m-',label='Fit')

axi.text(0.75,0.8,'T=%4.1f(K)'%ptitle, fontsize=7,transform = axi.transAxes)
axi.text(0.05,0.45,r'$\chi^2$=%3.1f'%chisq,fontsize=7,transform = axi.transAxes)
ytlist=np.linspace(min(ydata),max(ydata),4)
axi.set_yticks(ytlist)
axi.set_xlim([xlow,xhi])
xtlist=np.linspace(xlow,xhi,6)
axi.set_xticks(xtlist)        
for label in (axi.get_xticklabels() + axi.get_yticklabels()):
    label.set_fontname('Arial')
    label.set_fontsize(5)
axi.legend(('Data','Fit'), 'upper left', shadow=False, fancybox=False,numpoints=1,
            frameon = 0,labelspacing=0.01,handlelength=0.5,handletextpad=0.5,fontsize=6)
```

Comment: Thanks,the function I have works. But I do not know how to add axes to subplot to plot the residual with the fit as a subplot to the subplot.

Comment: Thank you Harry, I am posting qiestion here first time, so could not figure how to post it properly, appreciate your help. I guess, most of the code after 11th line is not of much concern, just to show what I have. after the line "axi.plot((x,fit,'m-',label='Fit')" I need to plot "Fit-ydata" which is the resudual as a subplot to this subplot. Thanks again!

Comment: I thought I added the figure but I can't see it now, I probably made a mistake that I don't understand. The figure supposed to show fit and the residual as an added axes sharing the xaxis below the subplot showing the residual.